# Chart.js setting maximum bar size of bar chart

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js

I want to limit the maximum width of a bar chart

**My CODE:**

```
    <script>
        // bar chart data
        var a=[];
            a.push('kalai 2015-04-11');
        var b=[];
            b.push('300');
        var barData = {
            labels : a,

            datasets : [
                {
                    fillColor : "#48A497",
                    strokeColor : "#48A4D1",
                    data : b

                }
            ]
        }
        // get bar chart canvas
        var income = document.getElementById("income").getContext("2d");
        // draw bar chart
        new Chart(income).Bar(barData, {scaleGridLineWidth : 1});
        <!--new Chart(income).Bar(barData);-->
    </script>
```

What is the way to do so

It looks like this for single value
[image: Single element]

The size of the bar reduces as the number of bar increases How can i set maximum bar size to make it more viewable

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29894577/chart-js-setting-maximum-bar-size-of-bar-chart?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add new options, which are not available by default.But you need to edit chart.js

In Chart.js add these lines of code
Step 1:

```
//Boolean - Whether barwidth should be fixed
        isFixedWidth:false,
        //Number - Pixel width of the bar
        barWidth:20,
```

Add these two line in defaultConfig of Bar Chart

Step 2:

```
calculateBarWidth : function(datasetCount){

                    **if(options.isFixedWidth){
                        return options.barWidth;
                    }else{**
                        //The padding between datasets is to the right of each bar, providing that there are more than 1 dataset
                        var baseWidth = this.calculateBaseWidth() - ((datasetCount - 1) * options.barDatasetSpacing);
                            return (baseWidth / datasetCount);
                    }
```

Add this condition in calculateBarWidth function of barchart

Now you can set barWidth in custom js file as option by setting

```
isFixedWidth:true,
barWidth:xx
```

If you don't want to specify fixed barwidth, just change `isFixedWidth:false`

Comment: Super ! Great solution , +100.

Comment: This  is a very helpful addition to Chart.js that I have used because of this answer, but I don't think fixedWidth and maxWidth are the same thing as the OP asked for.

Answer (score 3):

Its kinda late to answer this but hope this helps someone out there... play around with barDatasetSpacing [ adds spacing after each bar ] and barValueSpacing [ adds spacing before each bar ] to be able to achieve your desired bar width.. example below when initiating your bar chart

```
... barDatasetSpacing:10, barValueSpacing:30, ...
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: It's never too late :).

Answer (score 1):

I did it by extending Bar chart, and calculating barValueSpacing dynamically. I use angular chartjs

```
var MAX_BAR_WIDTH = 50;
Chart.types.Bar.extend({
            name: "BarAlt",
            draw: function(){
              var datasetSize = n // calculate ur dataset size here
              var barW = this.chart.width / datasetSize;
              if(barW > MAX_BAR_WIDTH){
                this.options.barValueSpacing = Math.floor((this.chart.width - (MAX_BAR_WIDTH * datasetSize)) / datasetSize);
              }
              Chart.types.Bar.prototype.draw.apply(this, arguments);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried following options?

```
{
    //Boolean - Whether the scale should start at zero, or an order of magnitude down from the lowest value
    scaleBeginAtZero : true,

    //Boolean - Whether grid lines are shown across the chart
    scaleShowGridLines : true,

    //String - Colour of the grid lines
    scaleGridLineColor : "rgba(0,0,0,.05)",

    //Number - Width of the grid lines
    scaleGridLineWidth : 1,

    //Boolean - Whether to show horizontal lines (except X axis)
    scaleShowHorizontalLines: true,

    //Boolean - Whether to show vertical lines (except Y axis)
    scaleShowVerticalLines: true,

    //Boolean - If there is a stroke on each bar
    barShowStroke : true,

    //Number - Pixel width of the bar stroke
    barStrokeWidth : 2,

    //Number - Spacing between each of the X value sets
    barValueSpacing : 5,

    //Number - Spacing between data sets within X values
    barDatasetSpacing : 1,

    //String - A legend template
    legendTemplate : "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=datasets[i].fillColor%>\"></span><%if(datasets[i].label){%><%=datasets[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>"

}
```

Comment: Yes I did i changes the barValueSpacing  it changed the distance between it but nothing changed the size of the bar

Comment: I am expecting  scaleGridLineWidth : 1, should work for you, I am unable to try this as I don't have working environment.

Comment: I have already implemented what you have said in my example code given it didn't change